# Prove that $\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)=2\arctan{x}$ for all $|x|<1$, directly from the integral definition of $\arctan$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

I would like to show that for $A(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$, we have $A\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)=2A(x)$, for all $|x|<1$.

My idea is to start with either $2\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$ or $\int_0^{2x/(1-x^2)}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$, and try to transform one into the other by change of variables. (It would make more sense for the moment if we did not do any trigonometric substitutions, since we are defining the trig functions via this integral.)

One of the several things I've tried is to use $A(x)+A(1/x)=\pi/2$, and write $\int_0^{2x/(1-x^2)}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\pi/2 - \int_0^{(1-x^2)/2x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\pi/2 - \int_0^{1/2x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^{x/2}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$, but this doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have to be a change of variables, or are other techniques (not using trigonometry) okay?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness; any technique is fine.

Comment: Ah, well, it's already posted.

Comment: The quiz at 7:30 AM on Monday will ask you to prove that $\displaystyle3\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2} = \int_0^{\large \frac{3x-x^3}{1-3x^2}} \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=A\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)$ and let $g(x)=2A(x)$, both defined by integrals precisely as in the OP.

Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to show that these functions have the same derivative. So they differ by a constant. Then all you will need to do is to show that they agree at say $x=0$, so the constant is $0$.

Comment: This method doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane:  I believe that it does. After some calculation, we find that $f'(x)=\frac{2}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: In fact the OP ask a method by using the integral definition of $\arctan$ and  your method is based on the derivation.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane But from the **integral definition** one gets that $(\arctan x)'=(1+x^2)^{-1}$.

Comment: But we don't need the integral defintion to find the derivation of $\arctan$.

Comment: Thanks very much, Andre! This is great.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: We do not need it if we define $\arctan x$ *geometrically*. But here we are defining it by an integral. This is much like the common *definition* of $\log x$ as $\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}$.

Comment: @EricAuld: You are welcome. So the calculation went smoothly! The reason for the restriction is that $\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ blows up at $\pm 1$, so beyond that we cannot use the theorem that if derivatives agree then functions differ by a constant.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The function $\arctan$ as I know is  defined as the inverse function of $\tan$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think the OP question is poorly written or I have misunderstood it, and therefore (+1) because the answer is correct and the OP is satisfied:)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I have I hope taken care of your objection by using $A$ instead of $\arctan$. I think it has led to more clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the calculation went fine. It makes sense that this restriction is here, because if we invert, we're looking at $\tan(2\theta)$, whose identity only works if $\theta \in (\pi/4, \pi/4)$, i.e. if $\tan \theta \in (-1,1)$.